# Ошибка при загрузке образа Docker

Tags: linux, docker

Пытаюсь загрузить образ из репозитория Docker:

```
$ docker pull ubuntu
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
Using default tag: latest
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/images/create?fromImage=ubuntu&tag=latest: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

Такое ощущение, что не хватает прав у пользователя.
Проверка статуса:

```
 sudo systemctl status docker
```

отрабатывает нормально.

Команда
`sudo usermod -aG docker $(whoami)`
вводилась.

Comment: а вы после добавления пользователя в группу релогинились или перезапускали систему?

Comment: Я перешел к root (sudo -i), попробовал ввести ту же команду-она отрабатывает без ошибок. И вернулся обратно к своему пользователю (exit). Попробовал еще раз-опять ошибка.